# Determine if connection is on 3G or WIFI network

Tags: control-center, sap-smp

I would know if there is a way to determine if the application connected using 3G or WIFI network.

Comment: I wonder what this has to do with Sybase?

Comment: I have to know on the SCC on what network users are synchronizing the application. I have other informations in the application connection properties, but I haven't on the 3G or wifi connection used

Comment: The name "Sybase" is usually used to identify a relational database. So what does this have to do with a wifi connection? Or does Sybase also build hardware for WiFi or 3G?

Comment: I thought I can find any connection informations on the CDB. I change the tags if you want sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to determine this on the server side only. The only thing you can check is the HTTP user agent, which will help you figure out the device. However a connection is just a connection, there's no way to determine how it is connected without the device telling you. If you are developing a **local** mobile application then you can either do different logic on the device or send additional information about the device's connection.

Comment: Thank you! How I can check the HTTP user agent? From the SCC?

Comment: @sharkbait unfortunately I'm not familiar with sybase. If you have a way to check HTTP request headers it will be in there.